# Storing order information (I have 2 options) like in a todo list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a list of items (like a todo list), that need to be presented in a certain order. This order may change, and new items may be added (at any position) and items deleted. I'm trying to decide what's a good way to store the order of these items, in a way that would make easy to update the list and display the data.

I could store the order information in a field for each item. This makes it easy to just sort the items by that field. But **the problem** is if I want to add a new item at the top of the list, I have to modify all other items in that list (if I have 50 todos, then I have to modify 50 records).

The other option is to store the order of the items in the todo list object itself. So I'd store the order as a string `23,45,34,100`. If the order changes, I just change that 1 field in the todo list object. **The problem** is that to present the items, I can't simply get them ordered. I have to figure out a way to order the items based on that order string, after I retrieve the items from the database.

So any tips on a good way to store the order bit? I have these 2 options, but I'm open to other ways. I'm looking for something that makes it easy to present the data, but not be too difficult to update the order when it changes.

```
Sample data

id     value     order 
----------------------
1      item 5    5    
2      item 1    1
3      item 4    4
4      item 2    2
5      item 3    3 

output
------ 
item 1 (id 2)
item 2 (id 4)
item 3 (id 5)
item 4 (id 3)
item 5 (id 1)
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired o/p

Comment: Though the update will be longer I think your first approach is the one that makes more sense. Keep order as a field in your database and you'll easily be able to query the information you need. PHP will just have to loop / update order if there is a change.

Comment: @mikevoermans My concern is not so much php, but the database itself. To update, I have to hit the database 50 times or more depending on the length of the list. That worries me a bit.

Comment: What is the scale of this? I was working on a database earlier this week that I ran 250,000 queries on. I also know some of my most commonly used CMSes store order fields in the database for navigation, or hierarchy. Its just a common practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT value
FROM Sampledata
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN id=2
THEN value END,
CASE WHEN id=4
THEN value END,
CASE WHEN id=5
THEN value END,
CASE WHEN id=3
THEN value END,
CASE WHEN id=1
THEN value END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an associative array, but the keys could be generated with uniquid().

You should store an ID as part of each item (perhaps generated with uniqid()), and keep an array of those IDs in the order in which they are sorted.  Then you keep your order as an array of IDs.

Change the order of the sort array, and you change the order of your output.  It is easy enough to output your values according to the sort array.

```
$values = array(
    '4f7684747c784' => array( ... ),
    '4f76846f0561c' => array( ... ),
    '4f76847aa7759' => array( ... ),
);

$sort = array('4f76846f0561c', '4f7684747c784', '4f76847aa7759');

foreach($sort as $key) {
    // do something with $values[$key]
}
```